# Pass Query string to WebMethod in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

What is the best way to get "test1" from

> http://localhost:3311/blabl/allprofiles.aspx?username=test1

, and through PageMethod pass it to webmethod. I think one way is to take from window.location.pathname, cut the string and pass it like a parameter.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use only javascript like:

```
var search = function(){
  var s = window.location.search.substr(1),
      p = s.split(/\&/),
      l = p.length, 
      kv, r = {};
  if(l === 0){return false;}
    while(l--){
      kv = p[l].split(/\=/);
      r[kv[0]] = kv[1] || true;
    }
    return r;
}();
```

Then use in your code `search.username`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string username = Request.QueryString["username"];
```

In a PageMethod, you can do

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"];
```

Comment: Yes, I try second one but I get null.